# How to Handle Image Orientation

Tags: swift, uiimagepickercontroller

I have an issue on capture image from camera. When I capture the image from camera using UIImagePickerController and after Capturing I save the image in my document directory and display it on my custom collectionView. But the problem is when I capture image and save it to document directory and when I load the image in my collectionView it display for the user on wrong orientation how can I handle the image orientation? I tried to save image as JPEG its work good but it support only one orientation. I want to save image as png because it support all orientation.

My code:

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {
    let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage

    // handle image orientation 

    //end

    // code for save image in document directory  from camera roll
    let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
    do {
        let document = try fileManager.URLForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomain: .UserDomainMask, appropriateForURL: nil, create: false)
        let getFolders = try fileManager.contentsOfDirectoryAtURL(document, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil, options: .SkipsHiddenFiles)
        var maxImageNumber:Int = 0 // for get the max number image in document directory
        for folder in getFolders {
            if folder.lastPathComponent! == albumName {
                let getImagesCheck = try fileManager.contentsOfDirectoryAtURL(folder, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil, options: .SkipsHiddenFiles)
                let getImages = try fileManager.contentsOfDirectoryAtURL(folder, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil, options: .SkipsHiddenFiles)

                if getImages.count <= 0 {
                    let imageUrl = folder.URLByAppendingPathComponent("Image \(getImagesCheck.count + 1).png")
                    if let convertImage = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) {
                        convertImage.writeToURL(imageUrl, atomically: true)
                    }
                }else {
                    // continue save images
                    let getImages_else = try fileManager.contentsOfDirectoryAtURL(folder, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil, options: .SkipsHiddenFiles)

                    for img in getImages_else {
                        let getImageName = img.lastPathComponent!
                        let arrayOne = getImageName.componentsSeparatedByString(".")
                        let arrayTwo = arrayOne[0].componentsSeparatedByString(" ")
                        let getImageNumber = Int(arrayTwo[1])
                        if getImageNumber! > maxImageNumber {
                            maxImageNumber = getImageNumber!
                        }
                    }

                    let imageUrl = folder.URLByAppendingPathComponent("Image \(maxImageNumber + 1).png")
                    if let convertImage = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) {
                        convertImage.writeToURL(imageUrl, atomically: true)
                    }

                }
            }
        }

    }catch {
        print(error)
    }

    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: One of the trick I used is that I would check the orientation of the image that I get and if it is in other orientation than in that of required then rotate it while displaying the image.

Comment: it is work with you ?